# adding an item in a list widget to another list widget

Tags: qt, qt4

I try to add an item in a list widget to another list widget when the button is clicked.I connected slot and signal.Then I wrote the code into called move function .My attempt is

> ui->topListWidget->addItem(ui->bottomListWidget->currentItem());

However it doesn't work. How can I do this or what's the problem of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//move existing item

> topListWidget->addItem(bottomListWidget->takeItem(bottomListWidget->currentRow()));

//add copied item

> topListWidget->addItem(bottomListWidget->currentItem()->text());

Answer (score 2):

QListWidget owns its items. One item cannot have two parents.

If you want to move an item from one list to another then use QListWidget::takeItem method. If you want to show items simultaniously in both lists then I advise you to give up on QListWidget and migrate to QListView.

Comment: What does "one item cannot have two parents" mean? If it happened, what would be? Thanks for reply.

Comment: C++ doesn't have garbage collector. Somebody have to delete objects on the heap explicitly. "Parent" in this context means an object that keeps track of its "children" ("owns" them) and will delete them when it'll be deleted itself. Obvisouly it's bad if two parents try to delete one children (programm will crash in this case), so having more then one parent is usually impossible by design.